# Is it correct to say "one out of *a* possible four"?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, indefinite-articles

I am curious if it is correct to say "one out of *a* possible four".

This is what I found in a publication:

> Discrete level (one out of a possible
>   four), corresponding to a range of
>   safety integrity values, where safety
>   integrity level 4 has the highest
>   level of safety integrity and safety
>   integrity level 1 has the lowest.

Comment: Yes, it is. Why would you wonder if the editor of the publication lacks the necessary knowledge to edit English?

Comment: maybe you could explain why you think it is wrong.

Comment: @nohat, @Marcin: someone not familiar with this construction (especially a non-native speaker) could find it surprising because one can’t simply say *\*one out of a four options*.  This seems grammatically intriguing to me: why are *a possible four options*, *an amazing thirty-nine flavours*, *an infamous fifty-two grammatical errors* all correct, but not *\*a ten letters*?  Anyone got a copy of CGEL or similar, to look up a professional analysis of what’s going on?

Comment: @PLL: Yes, that is how I was thinking.

Comment: The question in the title should finish with a question mark, not with a full stop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saying *x out of a possible y*, where *y* is a number that normally doesn't take an article, is quite common. It is **idiomatic** and correct. It is not informal or slang. It happens with any adjective, not just with *possible*.

It is correct to say *one out of four*, but not * *one out of possible four.* If I were to hazard a guess, I'd say the reason is probably that *possible* is an adjective, which can normally only be used to modify a noun (*a possible cause*), while *four* is not a noun but a cardinal number, which modifies a noun itself (*four camels, one woman*) and is not preceded by an article. But some cardinal numbers are also nouns, like *a hundred, a thousand*, etc. That's why it is quite unremarkable that we say *a possible hundred*. When the need arises to turn a lower number into a noun, because we want to modify it with an adjective, we use the article just as we do with *a hundred*, to form *a possible four*. In other cases, there is no need to nominalize ("nounify") because an article would be redundant, as in * *I see a one horse*.

I believe *one level out of four* is short for *one level out of four levels*; adding *possible* would give *one level out of four possible levels*. Shortening that would give *?one out of four possible*, but that is somehow not preferred with adjectives (it is common with (fossilized) participles: *one out of four remaining*). For some reason we prefer turning *four* into a noun and putting the adjective before it, calling up the article *a* as above.

Something similar is probably behind *we came back in **twos***: when the word *two* is used to mean *a set of two*, i.e. a noun, we may want to pluralize it. That is normally not possible with *two*, since it isn't a noun; but we can turn it into a noun and add the *s* in certain circumstances.

There are also personal pronouns, which function much the same as nouns, expect that they normally cannot take articles, adjectives, or cardinal numbers: * *Two they left my house* is impossible. But sometimes we want to specify how many things or persons are referred to by a pronoun. Because a personal pronoun can be the object of the preposition *of*, as in *part of him, several of us*, that is how we do it: ***two*** of us left, after **the two** of you. For that we turn the number *two* into a noun. As such it is modified by a prepositional phrase (*of us, of you*) and can take the definite article *the*.

Comment: It’s also perfectly good style: see for instance [plenty of examples](http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22a+possible+four%22+site:nytimes.com) in the New York Times.

Comment: I would suggest that the "four" here is similar to the usage "they came back in ones and twos", where the number n stands for "a set of n". What is that called, using a number to refer to a collection?

Comment: @JefSahol: It is turning a cardinal number into a noun. It is normally impossible, except in *a hundred, a thousand, a million,* etc., and all numbers starting with any of those words, like *a hundred thousand*; but in special circumstances it is possible with all cardinal numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct English. It's commonly used, and has no violations of ordinary rules of grammar.

"a possible *n*" refers to a set of *n* possibilities; "one out of a set of *n* possibilities" presents no grammatical difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Something the existing answers have overlooked is that four is **not** (merely) the number of possibilities.  It is **itself** a possibility.  The levels are `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }`.

An analogous situation would be *The judges gave the Olympic skater 9.7 out of a possible 10.*  They could have given "a 10".  Similarly the integrity level could be "a 4".