# Is this ellipsis or can 'guilty' be used as a noun?

Tags: nouns

Can *guilty* be used as a noun?
For example, as in the title of Chase's novel: *The guilty are afraid*.
Is it that *people* or *folks* is understood after guilty and in effect an ellipsis?
I do not find *guilty* marked as a noun in Webster or Wikitionary.

Comment: Have you never heard of the hungry, the poor, the rich? The lame and the blind? The fast and the furious? The good, the bad, and the ugly?

Comment: (Also, I think this might be a duplicate, though of course it's hard to search for this kind of thing, so the original might take some time to find.)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27690/is-it-correct-to-say-one-out-of-a-possible-four which deals with the nounifying of adjectives.

Comment: @RegDwighт♦: Indeed. An awful lot of "unlikely" terms can serve as nouns - witness ["the haves and the have nots"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+haves+and+the+have+nots%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Is there a post for the verbifying of nouns? :-)

Answer (score 4):

English is flexible. Native speakers often change the part of speech to suit their need at the moment. In this case, by using the definite article **the**, we can "*noun* [This noun has been turned into a verb -- *that is, **it functions as a verb***] *the adjective*", thereby turning "**the guilty**" into a noun.

Comment: It's called [conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(linguistics)), and my favorite exmple is: Verbin weirds language.

Comment: Maybe it is these days, but 30 years ago when I got my MA in theoretical linguistics it wasn't, as far as I know. Terminology changes, but I prefer Andrew Leach's very specific term "nounifying of adjectives" to the boringly vague "conversion", don't you?

Comment: And of course *adjective* itself is, morphologically and etymologically, a nouned adjective.

Comment: Yes, the adjective remains an adjective but it functions as a noun because the noun has been elided. These nounified adjectives are normally noncount nouns, but some, like "innocent" have plural forms, as in Mark Twain's novel _The Innocents Abroad_. "The guilty", however, cannot be "the guilties", nor can the "pure" be "the pures", "the good" "the goods", "the bad" "the bads", but "the ugly" can be "[the uglies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uglies)". Language is fascinating because it generates so many exceptions to the rules we love to impose but can't enforce, bellow as we might about them.

Answer (score 1):

Noun
[guilty](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guilty#Noun) (plural **guilties**) [wiktionary]
- (*law*) A plea by a defendant who does not contest a charge.
- (*law*) A verdict of a judge or jury on a defendant judged to have committed a crime.
- **One who is declared guilty of a crime**. [emphasis mine; usu. ***the*** guilty]

Although the word is essentially an adjective, extensive usage in the elliptical sense must have prompted some newer language resources to recognize *guilty* as a noun as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is ellipsis of a noun phrase.

*The guilty* is *the guilty [people]*, with the noun omitted. They have no difference in meaning. Similarly, we have *The Good[people], the Bad [people], and the Ugly [people]*.

There may be some room to quibble about terminology ("Ahhh... but... it is acting as a noun..."), but in *the guilty*, 'guilty' is still an adjective in a noun phrase, modifying an absent noun, so it isn't really 'nounifying' or conversion.

You may find this article interesting: [The Use of Adjectives as Nouns in English](http://www.brighthubeducation.com/english-homework-help/40011-the-use-of-adjectives-as-nouns/)